# Visual Studio Express 2013 Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT)

Tags: asp.net, command-line, visual-studio-2013, configuration-management

I am trying to access the Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT) so I can manage the users and roles established by an earlier version of VS. Apparently Microsoft took it away. I have Googled a solution, but I am not successful.

In the command prompt I entered...

```
iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:/WebAdmin /port:12345 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

I get an error...

```
c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe is not a valid Win32 application.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I think you mean the Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT), not Configuration Manager (which is something totally different, and configures your build configurations).

Comment: I am now having an error to access the WebAdmin through the browser. "An error was encountered. `Please return to the previous page and try again." ` I get that when I try to fire up the URL from the system tray (IIS Express > Development Web Site > http://localhost:12345/WebAdmin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repaired the IIS Express installation and it fixed the issue. The file had a size of zero when I looked at it before the repair.